# A question related to the ffmpeg input file list

Tags: ffmpeg

Below is a list of my files:

- Var_1m.jpg
- Var_5m.jpg
- Var_11m.jpg
- Var_20m.jpg
- Var_35m.jpg
- Var_47m.jpg
  ...

My goal is to create an mp4 video out of these image files. How do I describe my files in a ffmpeg script?
"Var_???m.jpg", or something similar?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with git / nightly / snapshot builds after July 2 2021 and in v5.0 when released.

Create a text file containing list of the images.

```
Var_1m.jpg
Var_5m.jpg
Var_11m.jpg
Var_20m.jpg
Var_35m.jpg
Var_47m.jpg
```

and then basic command is

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i concatf:list.txt out.mp4
```

Add `-framerate X` just before `-i` to set a framerate of X.

The [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) can be used in older builds.

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately, I got the below error:    libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
concatf:list.txt: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:concatf:list.txt?
(base) MacBook-Pro % ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)